# Using ASP .Net SignalR for Long Polling for a single client?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, streaming, iis-7.5, signalr, long-polling

I have this problem in which I need to compress (zip) multiple files from the web app (on the server) before streaming it down to the browser.  I'm pulling the files from a separate service that connects to a SQL database.  So there's a huge delay in opening the files from the service as well as a delay in compressing the files before the zipped package can be streamed to the browser.  Ideally, I would like to have the DOWNLOAD button on the page make a call to a SignalR method on the server which will then push a notification back to the client once the multiple files are done compressing.  That way, the browser won't request the server to stream the zipped file right away.  It will only begin streaming once the multiple files are done compressing.

background info:  I'm using IIS 7.5 and MVC 4.

I've been reading up and watching videos on SignalR, but have only seen examples of chat hubs and pushing to multiple clients, etc.  Would it be possible to only use SignalR for the client that is making the request?  And if so, I would appreciate some example code or perhaps a link to a tutorial on how one could accomplish something like this.  Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't sound like long polling at all actually. The functionality you want done is very, very similar to how chat hubs do it --- one client pushes data to the server, server then pushes that data to others. In your case, one client requests a download, then the server pushes the payload back to the same client once it's ready. Really, really similar mechanisms, and unless there's something really special about the nature of your process, it should be fairly easy to adapt the code samples you've been seeing.

Comment: Long Polling is one of the ways SignalR communicates, all the functionality of SignalR can be used with any underlying communication method, be it Long Polling, Web Sockets, or else. now in your case its as @RichardNeilIlagan, use the sample chat app, and instead of sending text, you can send files(byte arrays)

Comment: The company I work for doesn't like to stream the file using AJAX for security reasons.  Does SignalR make use of AJAX to communicate back and forth between Client and Server?  The idea I had was to simply use SignalR to "signal" (no pun intended) the client to let it know that it can now request a download.  The client would then request a file and the download process would happen as normal (ie, the server would stream the file using normal http process).  Is this doable with SignalR?

Comment: Yes it is, you can call a function with a filename parameter on the client from the server based on a timer or a another client call(JavaScript from your download page) and then the client will request the file normally.

Comment: I'm actually pulling the file from a web service.  Is there any way I can pull the file in memory from the server and then trigger the client to make an httpRequest to stream that file?  Or, does the file have to be persisted on a hard disk on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you need, you will have to define 3 clients

- **The Browser**, it will call **The Hub** when a download is requested, then it will wait for a call from **The Hub** to download the files.
- **The Server**, receives a notification from **The Hub** when the browser requests a download, and when all is ready calls **The Hub** to pass the files.
- **The Service**, received the files from **The Hub** when its passed from *The Server*, and make the files ready for download, then send a notification to **The Hub** to inform *The Browser*.

**Note**

Storing **large files** in memory is not recommended, and passing it through SignalR is not as well, unless its the only way the server and the service can share the files, so if you have a common storage -Disk or Database- then its better to use it